# Is there something wrong with this sentence? 暑いから水を飲みました。

Tags: word-choice, nuances, particle-から

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3_-LuElzfA&index=7&list=PLINFE8v4DOhsq0scG83kB5CRnowYWGSH7) explaining から. In it (at :08 and again at 2:29), the instructor shows a scene where he is drinking water, and says ”暑いから水を飲みました。”, then a buzzer noise and a big red X shows up. He then goes on to a scene where he is taking off his shirt and says, ”暑いから脱｛ぬ｝ぎました”. This sentence gets a ding and a green circle. He doesn't explain this, so I can't tell if he is making some kind of joke (perhaps about his preference for getting nude vs drinking water in response to hot weather), or if he is saying the first sentence is wrong for some reason. Is it? Why?

Note that I would have asked in a comment on the video, but someone already did that 6 months ago and hasn't gotten a response from the author of the video.

Comment: I am at work so will refrain from watching the video, but grammatically the first one is fine... especially considering how the trend in Japan is to have zero tolerance to heat, yet still totally overdress and deny yourself vitamin D.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic: It just shows the middle of his back for a brief second, if you're worried about nsfw.

Comment: This is not a question of grammar to begin with.  It is a question of word choice.

Comment: @l'électeur: Is it? I'm not asking whether you should prefer to say "Because it's hot, I took off my clothes" over "Because it's hot, I drank water". That wouldn't even be a language question, I think. I am asking if one of the sentences would be grammatically correct and the other one wouldn't, for some reason, even though they appear (to me) to be a nearly identical construction.

Comment: From Japanese point of view, I found nothing grammatically wrong with that sentence! As you say, it must be some sort of joke - if you feel hot you should take your clothes off but not drink water - which I think is wrong XD Going out without water in hot summer makes you sick and even kills you, literally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 暑いから水を飲みました is natural.